# Building an autoencoder with Keras and Kedro

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder, kedro

I'm trying to build an autoencoder, which I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. I tried separating the creation of the model from the actual training but this is not really working out for me and is giving me the following error.

```
AssertionError: Could not compute output KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 310), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dense_7/Sigmoid:0', description="created by layer 'dense_7'")
```

I'm doing this all using the Kedro framework. I have a pipeline.py file with the pipeline definition and a nodes.py with the functions that I want to use. So far, this is my project structure:

pipelines.py:

```
from kedro.pipeline import Pipeline, node
from .nodes.autoencoder_nodes import *

def train_autoencoder_pipeline():
    return Pipeline([
        # Build neural network
        node(
            build_models, 
            inputs=[
                "train_x", 
                "params:autoencoder_n_hidden_layers",
                "params:autoencoder_latent_space_size",
                "params:autoencoder_regularization_strength",
                "params:seed"
                ],
            outputs=dict(
                pre_train_autoencoder="pre_train_autoencoder",
                pre_train_encoder="pre_train_encoder",
                pre_train_decoder="pre_train_decoder"
            ), name="autoencoder-create-models"
        ),
        # Scale features
        node(fit_scaler, inputs="train_x", outputs="autoencoder_scaler", name="autoencoder-fit-scaler"),
        node(tranform_scaler, inputs=["autoencoder_scaler", "train_x"], outputs="autoencoder_scaled_train_x", name="autoencoder-scale-train"),
        node(tranform_scaler, inputs=["autoencoder_scaler", "test_x"], outputs="autoencoder_scaled_test_x", name="autoencoder-scale-test"),

        # Train autoencoder
        node(
            train_autoencoder, 
            inputs=[
                "autoencoder_scaled_train_x",
                "autoencoder_scaled_test_x",
                "pre_train_autoencoder", 
                "pre_train_encoder", 
                "pre_train_decoder",
                "params:autoencoder_epochs",
                "params:autoencoder_batch_size",
                "params:seed"
            ],
            outputs= dict(
                autoencoder="autoencoder",
                encoder="encoder",
                decoder="decoder",
                autoencoder_history="autoencoder_history",
            ),
            name="autoencoder-train-model"
        )])
```

nodes.py:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf

from typing import Dict, Any, Tuple
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging


def build_models(data: pd.DataFrame, n_hidden_layers: int, latent_space_size: int, retularization_stregth: float, seed: int) -> Tuple[keras.Model, keras.Model, keras.Model]:
    assert n_hidden_layers >= 1, "There must be at least 1 hidden layer for the autoencoder"
    
    n_features = data.shape[1]
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(n_features,))
    
    hidden = keras.layers.Dense(n_features, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(retularization_stregth))(input_layer)
    hidden = keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(hidden)
    
    for _ in range(n_hidden_layers - 1):
        hidden = keras.layers.Dense(n_features, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(retularization_stregth))(hidden)
        hidden = keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(hidden)
    
    encoded = keras.layers.Dense(latent_space_size, activation="sigmoid")(hidden)

    hidden = keras.layers.Dense(n_features, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(retularization_stregth))(encoded)
    hidden = keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(hidden)
    
    for _ in range(n_hidden_layers - 1):
        hidden = keras.layers.Dense(n_features, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(retularization_stregth))(hidden)
        hidden = keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(hidden)
    

    decoded = keras.layers.Dense(n_features, activation="sigmoid")(hidden)

    # Defines the neural networks
    autoencoder = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=decoded)
    encoder = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=encoded)
    decoder = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=decoded)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_absolute_error")

    return dict(
        pre_train_autoencoder=autoencoder,
        pre_train_encoder=encoder,
        pre_train_decoder=decoder
    )

def fit_scaler(data: pd.DataFrame) -> MinMaxScaler:
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(data)
    return scaler

def tranform_scaler(scaler: MinMaxScaler, data: pd.DataFrame) -> np.array:
    return scaler.transform(data)

def train_autoencoder(
    train_x: pd.DataFrame, test_x: pd.DataFrame, 
    autoencoder: keras.Model, encoder: keras.Model, decoder: keras.Model, 
    epochs: int, batch_size: int, seed: int) -> Dict[str, Any]:

    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.History(),
        keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3)
    ]
    logging.info(train_x.shape)
    logging.info(test_x.shape)

    history = autoencoder.fit(
        train_x, train_x,
        validation_data=(test_x, test_x),
        callbacks=callbacks, 
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size
    )

    return dict(
        autoencoder=autoencoder,
        encoder=encoder,
        decoder=decoder,
        autoencoder_history=history,
    )
```

catalog.yaml:

```
autoencoder_scaler:
  type: pickle.PickleDataSet
  filepath: data/06_models/autoencoder_scaler.pkl

autoencoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/autoencoder.h5

encoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/encoder.h5

decoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/decoder.h5

autoencoder_train_x:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: data/04_feature/autoencoder_train_x.csv

autoencoder_test_x:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: data/04_feature/autoencoder_test_x.csv
```

And finally parameters.yaml:

```
seed: 200
# Autoencoder
autoencoder_n_hidden_layers: 3
autoencoder_latent_space_size: 15
autoencoder_epochs: 100
autoencoder_batch_size: 32
autoencoder_regularization_strength: 0.001
```

I believe that Keras is not seeing the whole graph since they will be out of the scope for the buld_models function, but I'm not sure whether this is the case, or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to set up your project locally and reproduce the error. To fix it, I had to add the `pre_train_*` outputs to the catalog as well. Therefore, it's my `catalog.yaml` file:

```yaml
autoencoder_scaler:
  type: pickle.PickleDataSet
  filepath: data/06_models/autoencoder_scaler.pkl

pre_train_autoencoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/pre_train_autoencoder.h5

pre_train_encoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/pre_train_encoder.h5

pre_train_decoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/pre_train_decoder.h5

autoencoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/autoencoder.h5

encoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/encoder.h5

decoder:
  type: kedro.extras.datasets.tensorflow.TensorFlowModelDataset
  filepath: data/06_models/decoder.h5
```

Also, I changed the return of `train_autoencoder` node to:

```py
return dict(
    autoencoder=autoencoder,
    autoencoder_history=history.history,
)
```

Note that I changed the `autoencoder_history` to return `history.history` since `MemoryDataset` can't pickle the object `history` by itself. The `history.history` is a dictionary with losses of train and validation sets.

You can find the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/arnaldog12/a3f7801fe3910c02f4bcea8be61b910c).

Comment: The pre-train models are passed as a MemoryDataSet, I don't have them in the catalog, it only saves after training

Comment: you're right, @JoãoAreias. I'll try to set up a kedro project locally to test it. What are the package versions of Kedro, Keras, and TensorFlow you're using?

Comment: kedro==0.17.3, tensorflow==2.5.0, and I'm using the Keras from withing TensorFlow

Comment: Hi, @JoãoAreias
I was able to reproduce your error and fix it. I edited the answer with the right answer. Hope it helps!